# Nextjs build failed with 'workerError'

Tags: typescript, build, next.js, yarnpkg

This is the error I receive upon building (production build with 'yarn build') a nextjs app.

I have no idea whatsoever with what this is and couldnt find resources.

Please help !!!

```bash
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'
    |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
    --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
    at writeChannelMessage (node:internal/child_process/serialization:127:20)
    at process.target._send (node:internal/child_process:839:17)
    at process.target.send (node:internal/child_process:739:19)
    at reportError (/home/rashid/code/projects/blog-web-next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1993)
    at reportClientError (/home/rashid/code/projects/blog-web-next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/processChild.js:1:1669)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

> Build error occurred
Error: Call retries were exceeded
    at ChildProcessWorker.initialize (/home/rashid/code/projects/blog-web-next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12037)
    at ChildProcessWorker._onExit (/home/rashid/code/projects/blog-web-next/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/jest-worker/index.js:1:12975)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12) {
  type: 'WorkerError'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This breaks at this step

```bash
info  - Collecting page data ...node:internal/child_process/serialization:127
    const string = JSONStringify(message) + '\n';
```

[Link to Github Repository](https://github.com/m3rashid/blog-web-next)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I also saw your comment on Github. As **balazsorban44** mentioned there it is related to axios. I also had the same version of axios such as in your project:

> "axios": "^0.27.2",

Delete your node_modules, lock file and this line. After add this version to your project:

```
yarn add axios@0.25.0
```

Try to deploy again. It worked for me.

Comment: it works great form me. all did was remove axios @0.27.2 from my file and ran yarn and it worked perfectly